# How to buld Hibernate criteria for nest entity

Tags: java, hibernate

It's very dumping question. But I need to ask.
How can we build hibernate complex criteria? 
I wrote two simple class and one class has a reference to another.
Here are my classes

```
public class CourseEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToOne
    private CourseTypeEntity type;

    @OneToOne
    private CompanyEntity company;
}
```

and

```
public class CourseTypeEntity {

    @Column
    private String code;

    @Column
    private String name;
}
```

and was trying to build criteria something like this.

```
crit = session.createCriteria(CourseEntity.class, "c");
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("c.id", 1l));
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("c.type.id", 1l));
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("c.company.id", 1l));
        crit.add(Restrictions.like("c.company.name", "oracle"));
```

is the right way to fetch the company.name filter, whenever the last line is added, it throws the exception.

Could someone help to fix this issue or any other alternative way to do the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add alias:

```
crit = session.createCriteria(CourseEntity.class, "c").createAlias("c.company", "company");
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("c.id", 1l));
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("c.type.id", 1l));
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("company.id", 1l));
        crit.add(Restrictions.like("company.name", "oracle"));
```